# How to check return of unnamed function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, foreach

I made the code below:

```js
mp.events.addCommand("admin", (player, targetPlayer, targetAdminLevel) => {
  mp.players.forEach((targetPlayer2) => {
    if (targetPlayer2 === targetPlayer) return true;
    else return false;
  });
  try {
    if (player.adminLevel < 8) throw "Error 1.";
    if (!targetPlayer) throw "Error 2.";
    if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Error 3.";
    //if (functionAbove = false) code
  }
});
```

I want to know how to check if the function mp.players.forEach is true or false, so I can add it to the try statement. Thanks.

I'm trying to check if there's a player online with the name typed on the second argument of the command. Example: /admin playerName. If it exists, return true and set his adminLevel; if it doesn't, return false.

The function I'm using: https://wiki.rage.mp/index.php?title=Pool::forEach

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve (hopefully with an example)?

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything. Use `.some()`, `find()`, `.findIndex()`, `.filter()` or a plain old `for` loop

Comment: The callback for `forEach` doesn't return anything. If you're looking to see if a particular player is in the `mp.players` array then use something like `Array.prototype.find`.

Comment: Hi, @Mureinik, I updated the code.

Comment: why don't you just move the if condition in a different function and call it inside the unnamed function in foreach?

Comment: Thank you, @Andreas and goto1. I'll inform myself about those callbacks.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, @TirthrajRao, but I'm also learning and want to know if I can do this the way I mentioned, and it's algo more organized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forEach, use .some, .filter, .find. If you are returning something like given:

```
array.some(obj=><condition>) //return boolean 

array.filter(obj=><condition>) //return array with all the elements which fulfills condition 

array.find(obj=><condition>) //return element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over object

```
const players = {
    player1 : 'Neimar',
    player2 : 'Carvalho',
    player3 : 'Ronaldinho'
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(players)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

You can setup condition as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to do:

```
global.findPlayer = function findPlayer(name) {
    let players = mp.players.toArray();
    for(let p in players) {
        if(players[p].name == name) {
            return players[p];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

if (findPlayer(targetPlayer)) //code;
```